# Limit of function $(-0.1)^x$ as $x$ approaches infinity

Tags: limits

$\lim_{x\to\infty}(-0.1)^x = ?$

What does the overall function approach? I'm unsure if it approaches $0$ or if it's nonexistent

Comment: $f(x) = (-.1)^x$ doesn't have a very nice domain ...

Comment: You are going to have lots of problems with exponents of the form $\;x=\frac  m{2k}\;,\;\;m,k\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;m\;$ odd.

Comment: "The overall function": how is it defined? Where is it defined? That should be the very first step: before asking for its answer, is your question well-defined?

Answer (score 3):

In order to *define* $(-0.1)^x$ you must use a complex logarithm $\log z = \ln|z| + i\arg z$ with a branch cut that allows for negative numbers, say the natural branch with $\arg z \in (0, 2\pi)$.

Then you have 
$$(-0.1)^x = e^{x \log(-0.1)} = e^{x(\ln|0.1|+i\pi)}$$ 
and consequently
$$|(-0.1)^x|=e^{x\ln|0.1|}=(0.1)^x \to 0 \ \mathrm{as} \ x \to \infty$$

Answer (score 0):

It is $0$ because for every $\epsilon>0$ there exists $c>0$ such that $|(-0.1)^x|<\epsilon$ for $x>c$. Simply pick $c=\log_{10}(1/\epsilon)$.

Comment: What is $(-0.1)^{25.7}$? (In a way the answer is right but the explication is not sufficient in my opinion.)

Comment: How do you define $(-0,1)^x$ for, say, $x=1000+\frac{1}{2}$? The function given by the OP is not defined on any neighborhood of $\infty$, at least without much further detail -- e.g., on a restriction of the domain.